# How to Pass image url as parameter in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

here is my .htaccess code

```
Options all -Indexes

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^thumb/(.*)$ thumb.php?imagePath=$1 [B]

</IfModule>
```

If i enter url as `http://mydomain.com/thumb/image1.jpg` then its passed to `thumb.php?imagePath=image.1`, and its working fine.

suppose if i enter url as `http://mydomain.com/thumb/http://otherwebsite.com/images/image1.jpg`

then its showing 404 error. Please help me to sort out this issue

And i used encodedurl too like this `http://mydomain.com/thumb/http%3A%2F%2Fotherwebsite.com%2Fimages%2Fimage1.jpg`

Same i got 404 Error. Please help me to sort out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a parameter with `http://` you need to use capture the URI using `THE_REQUEST` variable. `THE_REQUEST` variable that represents original request received by Apache from your browser

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+thumb/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ thumb.php?imagePath=%1 [B,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working :) but i have a small doubt is the htaccess code having security hole? will it allow to hack kind of things?

Comment: No I don't think it any risk if your thumb.php is just doing image displaying job. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Why have you add a `/` at the end of your rule ?

Try this :

```
Options all -Indexes

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^thumb/(.*)$ thumb.php?imagePath=$1 [B]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: really thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately still i have same 404 error :S

Comment: Can you check your access.log files to see exactly what happens ?

Comment: the error.log file is empty. and i tried the url many time, still the error.log is empty

Comment: Sorry, I would mean the access.log file.

Comment: i seen nothing on access.log related to the thumb/ things :(